# Item is not updating if an attribute is changed (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, list, android-jetpack-compose

I am drawing a list of devices

```
@Composable
fun DeviceListScreen(){
  val model: DeviceListViewModel = hiltViewModel()

  val myDevices: List<MyDevice> by model.myDevices.observeAsState(emptyList())
  for(device in myDevices)
    Device(device)
}
```

In model I have a livedata

```
private val items: List<MyDevice> = ArrayList()
private val _myDevices = MutableLiveData<List<MyDevice>> (emptyList())
val myDevices: LiveData<List<MyDevice>> = _myDevices
```

I change content of an item then update live data

```
items[0].signal = 54
_myDevices.value = items
```

However data is not updating in ui.
I guess this is because the pointer to list was not changed and number of items in the list also is not changes and thus compose does not update this data.

Comment: I think you should use 'observeAsState'

Answer (score 2):

**Update 12-08-2022**

I've just encountered the same problem you had. I have successfully solved it, so the following solution that I have adapted for your problem should also work fine:

```
fun updateSignal(idOfSelectedDevice: Int) {
  _myDevices.value = myDevices.value?.map { device ->
    if (device.id == idOfSelectedDevice) device.copy(
        signal = <YOUR_DESIRED_VALUE>
    ) else device
  }
}
```

---

You could try wrapping `items` in its own data class:

```
data class ItemsList(val devices: List<MyDevice> = ArrayList())
```

Then change items to `private val items: ItemsList = ItemsList()`

Since you are using your own data class for `items`, you can then access the *copy* function which copies an existing object into a new object and should therefore trigger the update of the liveData object:

```
_myDevices.value = _myDevices.value?.copy(items = items.devices.apply { 
    this[0].signal = 54
})
```

Comment: Recomposition is called for whole list. But recomposition is not calling for specific item. I think this is because object reference did not change. Only property `signal` is changed but this seems not enought.

Comment: See updated answer above